# Finding the value of constants

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Find the value of $a$ and $b$ if the curves $y=x^2+ax+b$ and $y=x-x^2$ meet at $(0,1)$ . That was the complete question . 
I tried it but felt that that the information was adequate.

Comment: The curve $y=x-x^2$ will not pass through the point $(0,1)$.

Comment: There are infinitely many parabolas that *intersect* $y=x-x^2$ at $(0,1)$.  But *meet* probably means they intersect and share a tangent line.

Comment: @AustinC, maybe he means $(1,0)$

Comment: Or at $(0,0)$, perhaps? Or $(1,0)$?

Comment: Sure.  Once that is corrected, I second Matthew's hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that they meet at $(1,0)$ and we follow Matthew's advice, we can find $a$ and $b$.

First note that for $y_1=x^2+ax+b$ to pass through $(1,0)$, we must have $0=1+a+b$ (by substituting 1 for $x$ and 0 for $y_2$).  Next, take the derivative of this function: $y_1'=2x+a$.  We would like this to match the derivative of $y_2=x-x^2$ at $x=1$, so we compute $y_2'=1-2x$ and find that $y_2'(1)=-1$.

By setting $2(1)+a=-1$, we find that $a=-3$.  Substituting this back into the condition $0=1+a+b$, we find that $b=2$.  So $y_1=x^2-3x+2$ and $y_2=x-x^2$ intersect at $(1,0)$ and have the same tangent line at this point.

If you meant a different point on $y_2=x-x^2$, this method can be easily adapted.